# loop through resources in kusto query language

Tags: loops, resources, kql

I have a query, I am trying to get uptime of all my vm's in a subscription. With the below query i am able to fetch uptime for one vm only. need to fetch for all vm's in that subscription, can any one help me please

```
let start_time = AzureActivity 
| where OperationName == "Start Virtual Machine" 
| where Resource contains "VMXXXXXX"
| project TimeGenerated
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc;
AzureActivity
| where Resource contains "VMXXXXXX"
| extend upTime = now() - toscalar(start_time)
| project upTime, Resource
| top 1 by upTime
```

I have tried modifying the above query, but not getting the required results.Here i have used workspace.

```
let start_time = AzureActivity 
| where OperationName == "Start Virtual Machine" 
| project TimeGenerated
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc;
workspace("abc1234567").AzureActivity
| extend upTime = now() - toscalar(start_time)
| project upTime, Resource
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How would you like to handle cases in which a VM is started, then stopped, then started again? Please edit the question to provide minimal sample input (that includes edge cases) using [datatable operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator), and expected output. Then ping us here by posting a comment.

Comment: hi Slavik, i am happy with my first query and i have validated the result too.. it is working fine, i am getting the correct up time for a single vm. now my question is - how can i apply to all the vm's. is there any loop

Comment: You've tagged your question as related to the [`vms`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) family of operating systems. How does you question relate to VAX or Alpha systems running OpenVMS?

Comment: Hi Habo,removed VMS tag

Comment: @phani, to help you I need sample input (using the datatable operator), and expected output.